# How can I push an unrelated history as a series of new commits?

Tags: git, rebase

I have two separate remote respositories, RemoteOld and RemoteNew.

**RemoteOld**
Uri: http://RemoteOld
Branches:
A--B--C--D--E master

**RemoteNew**
Uri: http://RemoteNew
Branches:
A'--B' master

I want to take all of the commits from RemoteOld and add them to RemoteNew, so that RemoteNew looks like this:

**RemoteNew**
Branches:
A'--B'--A--B--C--D--E master

Commit A in RemoteNew/master should effectively remove all the files in RemoteNew and replace them with the files in a snapshot of RemoteOld/master at Commit A. Commits B-E should be the same between RemoteOld and RemoteNew. I need to do this without using a force push.

Comment: _"without using a force push"_? I'm not sure you can. They won't be identical without it

Comment: @evolutionxbox the histories don't have to be identical, just the contents of the files at HEAD. There is no reason that this should require a force, because I'm not overwriting any history

Comment: The arrows go the other way: a branch name points to the *last* commit, and each commit points backwards to an earlier one. You must force-push whenever you're asking a repository to change a branch name from pointing to commit X to pointing to commit Y if and only if X is *not* already an ancestor of Y.

Comment: @torek what if I create new commits with the same names and changes?

Comment: It doesn't matter what's *in* the commits, *except* for the history arrows. The new commit must point backwards to some existing commit, through the chain.

Comment: You can put whatever files you like in any new commit, and have the new commit point backwards to whatever used to be the last commit in the chain; then `git push` will generally accept it (though each repository can add its own restrictions).

Comment: @torek Thats what I'm saying. I want to create a new commit named FirstCommitOld that  points to FirstCommitNew and makes the contents of the files match the contents of RemoteOld at FirstCommitOld. I can do it by making the changes manually, so why couldn't I do it programatically?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is a fairly straight-forward use of [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). Have a look around, and you'll probably find plenty of instructions on how to use that.

Comment: Rebase FirstCommitNew (RemoteNew master) on top of FirstCommitOld (RemoteOld master).

Comment: I'm just saying you've drawn the arrows the wrong way around. Draw them the right way, state that the content of new commit `a123456...` is whatever files you like and that the parent of `a123456` is existing commit `0987654...` or whatever. Show that the `git push` will ask their repository to set *their* master to `a123456` which now comes after `0987654` and you have shown that `--force` isn't required.

Comment: Since history *is* the set of commits in a repository, adding on a new commit produces *related history*.

Comment: @torek the history of RemoteOld is unrelated to RemoteNew

Comment: Just to clarify. You want the files to match?

Comment: That's irrelevant. The history of the *individual Git repository* is what is relevant. The commits in any one repository can have related file contents, or not; they *must* have the right hash IDs so that they are related *commits*. That's all that matters.

Comment: Remember also that the *files in a commit* are a *snapshot*. You can replace this wholesale any time you like. Just `git rm` every existing file and `git add` every new file and you have a new snapshot.

Comment: @evolutionxbox What I mean by that is all the files in RemoteNew/master (except .git folder of course) should be identical to RemoteOld/master after the operation is done

Comment: @torek I know that, and that is not helpful. Please re-read the question, especially my recent edit

Comment: If you have a linear sequence of commits you'd like to add, you can add the first one as a copy and then "play back" all the subsequent ones (turning them into chnages and applying, i.e., `git rebase`). But in general that's not the way to go because it only works if the commits are purely linear: rebase doesn't work with branch-and-merge graphs. So instead, the way to do this is with filter-branch, or filter-repo, or perhaps in this case fast-export and fast-import. I'd have to experiment with the latter two though.

Comment: One other method would be to use `git fetch` to collect all commits together, then use `git replace` to make a splice (history graft), then run a no-op filter-(branch|repo) to convert all commits to new ones to cement the graph without `git replace`, ditch the replacement commit, and call it done.

Comment: @torek how can I even get both branches named master (one from RemoteOld and one from RemoteNew) into the same local repository?

Comment: They won't both have the same name to locate their final commit: `git fetch` makes *remote-tracking* names, not *branch* names (by default anyway).

Comment: I have updated the question because people didnt seem to understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rebase RemoteOld/master onto RemoteNew/master. Since both branches have the same name you will need to temporarily rename a branch:

1. Clone RemoteOld:

   ```
    git clone http://RemoteOld
    cd FolderCreatedByClone
   ```
2. Add RemoteNew. You can remove RemoteOld while you are at it because this won't be used anymore:

   ```
   git remote add RemoteNew http://RemoteNew
   git remote rm origin
   ```
3. Rename RemoteOld/master to some other name, like masterOld. Fetch the master branch from new origin. Then run `git branch -a` to see all the branches:

   ```
   git branch -m masterOld
   git fetch RemoteNew
   git branch -a
   ```

Output:

```
 *masterOld
 remotes/RemoteNew/master
```

4. Rebase masterOld onto RemoteNew/master:

   ```
    git rebase --onto master masterOld
   ```
5. At this point masterOld will look like what you want RemoteNew/master to look like, so just merge masterOld into RemoteNew/master.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge masterOld
   ```
6. Push RemoteNew/master. The old master branch can be deleted.

   ```
   git branch -d masterOld
   git push
   ```

Comment: `git rebase --onto master masterOld` this might need the allow unrelated histories flag?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didnt need that flag

Comment: So it didn’t warn you that they’re unrelated?

Comment: @evolutionxbox nope